# popover is not working in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I am using UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate to show my popover, it's working fine but not able to manage width and height of the popover viewController. And how to set Presentation over current context ??

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let showObjectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowActorDetail") as! ShowActorDetailsViewController
    showObjectVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

    showObjectVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    showObjectVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    showObjectVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)

    present(showObjectVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Is it for iPad or iPhone?

Comment: It's for  iPhone

Answer (score 0):

instead of going with `preferredContentSize` try using the `sourceRect` property of `UIPopoverPresentationController` like,

```
showObjectVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.frame
```

Make sure to point the frame of cell as you need in order for the popover to show at you desired position.

Answer (score -1):

You can try another approach:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let showObjectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowActorDetail") as! ShowActorDetailsViewController
    // your logic
    presentViewControllerAsPopUp(showObjectVC)
}

private func presentViewControllerAsPopUp(_ vc: UIViewController) {
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    //self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In `ShowActorDetailsViewController` you can make `UIView` with needed size and colored background.